# How to compute land cover values from another raster?

Tags: r, raster, tiff

I have two rasters:

```
raster1
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 2803, 5303, 14864309  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent     : 60.85, 105.0417, 15.95833, 39.31667  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
source     : memory
names      : npp 
values     : -0.345, 1.723  (min, max)

raster2
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 2803, 5303, 14864309  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent     : 60.85, 105.0417, 15.95833, 39.31667  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
source     : C:/a/b/Documents/c/landuse.tif 
names      : landuse
values     : 1, 12  (min, max)
attributes :
       ID                          zn
 from:  1 evergreen needleleaf forest
  to : 12                   croplands
```

`raster2` is a land cover types of a specific region and `raster1` is values of net primary productivity. I would like to compute how much net primary productivity is in each land cover class in `raster 2`. How could I achieve this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the sum of the values of the cells in r1 for each land cover code in r2, output returned as a list. Could instead use lapply.

```r
library(raster)

#Generate example data
raster1 <-  raster(matrix(c(1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7),ncol =3))

raster2 <- raster(matrix(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),ncol =3))
raster2 <- as.factor(raster2)

rat <- levels(raster2 )[[1]]
rat[["landcover"]] <- c("land","ocean/lake", "rivers")
levels(raster2 ) <- rat

#Extract sum of values of raster 1 for each level of raster 2
Val <- list()
for(lc in levels(raster2)[[1]]$ID){
  Values <- raster1[raster2[]==lc]

  Val[[lc]] <- sum(Values)
}
```

Comment: It worked! However I want to clarify that will it be wise to use `Val[[lc]] <- mean(Values)` instead of `Val[[lc]] <- sum(Values)`? Because when mean is taken the values are making more sense.

Comment: That depends on your question, I'm afraid. If you want to know the NPP in a typical cell in say croplands vs woodland then mean makes more sense. If you want to know how much npp in your study area is produced by croplands then use sum.